# Conditional Irwin-Hall Distribution: What is the expected value of an Irwin-Hall given that it is greater than some value?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Take $n$ i.i.d.uniform distributions. Their sum, $X$, is an Irwin-Hall distribution with support $[0,n]$: $$X=\sum_{k=1}^nU_k.$$ Naturally, the mean of $X$ is $\frac{n}{2}$. What if I am only concerned with values greater than some $a\in[0,n]$? What is the mean of $X$ given that $X>a$?

Comment: $E\left[X\mid X>a\right]=\frac{1}{P(X>a)}E\left[XI_{X>a}\right]$

Comment: That, of course,  would be the mean of a truncated Irwin-Hall distribution. I don't think you'll get a simple expression for it (not simpler that writing the CDF of the IH distribution). Consider that, for large $n$, it would tend to a truncated normal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution